# How can I keep session open after login?

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a login in my project but always when I open my app after I close it, have to login again. I use Firebase to authenticate, but I want something like:

```
check if user is logged -> 
if not - open login, 
else - open my main activity"
```

I don't know if I have to use SQLite or something or exist how to keep session alive even you close the application if user doesn't log out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED! found this and works 100%

```
  @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        if (user != null) {

            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, MainActivity.class));
        } else {
            //returns to login
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using Firebase to autenticate, you can easily verify if a user is autenticated like this:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (firebaseUser != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are signed in Firebase!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Redirect to MainActivity
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You are signed out from Firebase!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //Redirect to LoginActivity
        }
    }
};
```

No need of SqLite. Hope it helps.

Comment: And the final step:  `auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @AlexMamo :) was helpfull but doesn't work for me, i found another option to do this, look at my answer if you want to know how i solved the problem.

Comment: @DaniGee, Your answer is the same of mine :)

Answer (score 0):

If current user is not null, means is logged in, null otherwise

```
boolean isUserLoggedIn = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set boolean flag when you login on sharedpreferences, so when you load your application you verify that flag, if it's true call some activity but if it's false call login activity.
Just remember to set flag to false when user logout.